# surface plot - too many connections

Tags: matlab

I have a surface plot in MATLAB, but it seems that too many points are connected.  The surface on the bottom is what I want to display, but all the endpoints are connected as well.  Is it possible to remove this?

```
I have 3 data vectors: x, y, and z

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

Here's the scatter plot of what my data looks like.

[image]

Comment: what function are you calling? can you show us some of your code/data

Comment: Have you tried to plot just the points with `scatter3(x,y,z)` to see what shape they form in 3D? Can you show this plot to have an idea about your data?

Comment: Are `x` and `y` sorted? This kind of thing often happens with unsorted independent variables.